# Ubuntu + CISCO VPNC CLIENT for my new ubuntu version (32 bit )

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I have newest Ubuntu Linux version 10.04.4 (32 bit )

I want to install Cisco VPNC client on this linux machines in order to connect to other customers

I little confuse ,

which VPNC cisco version will fit for my Ubuntu Linux machine , I see in google allot of information

But I can’t understand what the right instruction ( which Vpn cisco version ) , in order to install VPN cisco client on Ubuntu Linux version 10.04.4 (32 bit ) ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need to install the Cisco VPN Client: NetworkManager includes support for Cisco IPSec VPNs.

Here is step by step guide to install Cisco VPN client on ubuntu:

1)Install **network-manager-vpnc** using the following command from your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
```

This will install **vpnc**, **network-manager-vpnc** and **network-manager-vpnc-gnome**.

2)Now you need to left click on your network manager applet (Located in your notification area) And choose "Configure VPN...":

[image]

3)Now click on Add:

[image]

4)Choose VPN connection type as "Cisco Compatible VPN(VPNC)" and click on create:

[image]

5)Enter your cisco VPN details under VPN tab:

[image]

6) Now you need to select IPV4 Settings tab click on routes:
[image]

7)Here you need to select "Use this connection only for resources on its network" click ok otherwise your traffic significantly slowed down:

[image]

8)To start your new VPN, just follow the steps again, but instead of "Configure VPN", you'll click on the entry you created.

Hope it could help.

Comment: thx rose for the clear answer . about ubuntu - I have Unbuntu desctop linux machine , but I think it will be better to install unbuntu server ( its more powerfull ) what you think? , do you work before with checkpoint VPN's?